# Importing a jQuery plugin in Angular project (tipsy)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I'm using Angular CLI and I'm trying to import a jQuery plugin. Particularly I'm tyring to import he 'tipsy' plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tipsy) .

So I added the following to the css in my styles of angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
    "assets/styles/custom.scss",
    "../node_modules/tipsy/src/stylesheets/tipsy.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
  ],
```

And in my scripts

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/tipsy/src/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "../node_modules/colresizable/colResizable-1.6.min.js"
  ]
```

But how to import it further into my component so I can use for example

```
$(this).tipsy()
```

?

I'm trying to use it with the d3 library. So it ends up in the following code:

```
g.append('path')
  .attr('class', 'solid')
  .attr('title', this.styleCapacityTip)
  .each(function(d) {
    if (isEditing()) {
      return;
    }
    $(this).tipsy({
      gravity: 's',
      opacity: 0.8,
      html: true
    });
  })
```

To import I already tried in my component:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import tipsy from 'jquery.tipsy';
```

But it returns

```
ERROR TypeError: $(...).tipsy is not a function
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Can you show us the styles and scripts parts of you .angular-cli.json ?

Comment: I've added some more information in my original question!

Comment: Using jQuery in Angular is not good practice

Comment: Is that type error in browser's console, or terminal console?

Comment: That error was in the browser's console.  I'm trying around meanwhile and right now I'm getting 
ERROR in src/app/shared/component/spectrum/spectrum.component.ts(4,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jquery.tipsy'.

Comment: Did you find a solution? You should not need to `import` the plugin with `import tipsy from 'jquery.tipsy';`, as it's not a real module. Did you restart `ng serve` after adding the plugin's code to `angular-cli.json` file?

Comment: I was not able to find the solution yet. I removed the imports now as you suggested. I can see that the tipsy code is available in the scripts.bundle.js but I still get the error `TypeError: $(...).tipsy is not a function`

Comment: As I was not able to import the tipsy I currently worked around it by changing this to work like http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369 .

It could be useful to still find a solution though